# Getting a value from list based on second list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

I have a problem to get the value from first list based on second list. We can assume that we have an election. First list is the list of candidates, second list is the list of votes for this candidates.

```
candidatesList = [1,2,3,4]
voteList = [2,4,4,1]
```

One of the rules of election is that, if two or more candidates got same amount of votes then the winner is a candidate with lower number. In this case above output should be **2**. I can change data structures but the output must be same.

Comment: Is the 1st list an index into the 2nd list?

Comment: Nope, I think to transform both lists to one dictionary, but still don't know how to get only right value on output.

Comment: What was your attempt?

Comment: I've tried to loop by first and second list and using additional variable. Also I wanted to use dicitionary, but I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Simplest way***

```
candidatesList[voteList.index(max(voteList))]
```

`max(voteList)` gets you the max of the votes.

`voteList.index(max(voteList))` gets you the index of the highest vote from the right hand side.
`candidatesList[...]` gets you the person

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, this might be what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np

candidates_list = [1,2,3,4]
vote_list = [2,4,4,1]

best_candidate_index = np.argmax(vote_list)
print("Best candidate", candidates_list[best_candidate_index])
```

Answer (score 0):

Create dataframe, sort by ['voteList','candidatesList'] and use the top row.

```
d = dict(candidatesList = [1,2,3,4], voteList = [2,4,4,1])
pd.DataFrame(d).sort_values(by=['voteList','candidatesList'], ascending=[False,True]).candidatesList.iloc[0]
```